# Prolong systemd "starting" status until process' internal state is ready

Tags: systemd

When you start a service with systemd, the process is only in the `activating` state for a moment.  It transitions to `active` once the process has successfully started.

But what if I have a complicated service that takes time until it is ready?  How can I prolong the `activating` state until the service is ready internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `[Service]` section of your unit, add (or change) [`Type=notify`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=).

This tells systemd that the process itself is going to signal when it has started.  Therefore systemd won't assume that it's ready when the process has started.

For this to work, the process has to implement [sd_notify(3)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html#).

---

Here's a minimal example of a notifying service in C:

```
# notifier.service
[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=%h/bin/notifier
```

```c
/* main.c */
#include <systemd/sd-daemon.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
        /* Sleep to emulate 10s bootup time */
        /* Expect status 'activating (start)' during this */
        /* `systemctl start`, will block */
        sleep(10);

        /* Send a signal to say we've started */
        sd_notify(0, "READY=1");

        /* Units which are After= this unit will now start */
        /* `systemctl start` will unblock now */

        /* Sleep to emulate 10s run time */
        /* Expect status 'active (running)' during this */
        sleep(10);

        /* Send a signal to say we've started the shutdown procedure */
        sd_notify(0, "STOPPING=1");

        /* Sleep to emulate 10s shutdown */
        /* Expect status 'deactivating' during this */
        sleep(10);

        return 0;

        /* Expect status 'inactive (dead)' at this point */
}
```

```
# makefile
a.out: main.c
        gcc main.c -lsystemd

install: a.out notifier.service
        install -D a.out ~/bin/notifier
        install -D notifier.service ~/.config/systemd/user/notifier.service
```

Comment: For extra points it would be nice to mention that `Type=dbus` and the traditional `Type=forking` also give ways to control when the unit is considered started.